# How do you recover dead node in HDInsight Hadoop (Linux) cluster?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

One of the worker nodes in my HDInsight Hadoop (Linux) cluster is dead (stopped sending heartbeat). Is there any chance that HDInsight Will try to rectify it ? If not, what is the way to bring it back online?

Comment: Have you considered contacting Microsoft? They can reboot the worker node to mitigate the issue.

Comment: That is time consuming process. I can delete and recreate the cluster, but this happened many times so I wanted to understand if there is any quick solution. Even deleting and recreating cluster should take some time, but instead if there is some command using which we can bring the dead node back to life, restart etc it is preferable.

Comment: If it's an Azure issue itself then most likely you can not do anything by yourself to restart it. On the other hand if it's HDInsight issue and by analyzing the logs you can understand the issue then you might be able to do something. But from the symptoms you described it looks like an azure issue and you can not restart a node when you can not even access it.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the node via ssh, if it is not the head ssh to it from the head node. Once on the node, restart the ambari-agent. The ambari-agent is what sends the heart beats.

Comment: But what if you can't even connect (SSH) to the node, you can't run any commands on that node then to restart the agent. It's cloud (Azure HDInsight) based cluster. I tried SSHing to the node (from headnode) but I get Connection time out.